# Place an image inside another image view in android

Tags: android, uiimageview, imageview, android-imageview

I'm trying to place an image inside another imageview in android. If user selects a number "1"  display that number image in another imageView. Is it possible to incorporate the image inside another. Please mention your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you can set two images in single `ImageView` using `Background` and `src` properties

Comment: Try to use framelayout layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to show two images in one image view would be by using `LayerDrawable`

```
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.t);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.tt);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
testimage.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList